How to Correct Arithmetic Underflow Overflow Error
I'm trying to code a 30minute delay in a smart contract and currently it looks like this
    uint256 futureTimestamp = block.timestamp + 1800; 
    uint256 timeDiff = block.timestamp - futureTimestamp;
    require(timeDiff > 1800, "30 minute delay has not passed yet");   

and I'm getting an underflow/overflow error. How can I correct this so the contract doesn't revert? I'm using solidity 0.8.10. I tried many different ways of writing the delay but this seemed to be the best.

You can't write a "delay" in a Ethereum smart contract. You can only prevent execution until certain time.
So what you need to do is store a future timestamp in the contract storage, and in a subsequent transaction (probably to a different function) check that the current timestamp is beyond the stored future timestamp, and only then allow execution.
So you need two transactions. The first one "initializes" the contract with a future timestamp, deciding when the second transaction can be executed. This can be done during the deployment transaction as well, in constructor. The second transaction calls the function that users can call only after the future timestamp.

futureTimestamp is always greater than block.timestamp, so block.timestamp - futureTimestamp results in an underflow error. futureTimestamp - block.timestamp would give you 1800 (but still fail the require statement since 1800 is not greater than 1800).
I believe what you're trying to do is store an initial value for the delay into a variable: delayTimestamp, then later check if the current time is greater than delayTimestamp + 1800.
uint256 timeDiff = block.timestamp - delayTimestamp // where delayTimestamp < block.timestamp
Note: Solidity >0.8 by default has an underflow check. If you intend for the operation to underflow, you can wrap the code in an unchecked {} block.

I realized when I looked at the math that it was in the wrong order. So I fixed it so it looks like   uint256 futureTimestamp = block.timestamp + 1800;
uint256 timeDiff = futureTimestamp - block.timestamp;
require(timeDiff >= 1800, "30 minute delay has not passed yet");                                                        but when I tested it the transaction completed immediately without waiting the 30 minutes. Is that normal in testing or am I missing a part of the function that would recheck if the condition isn't met?

I think you're missing something. You're just setting a variable to be equal to now + 30 minutes and checking if it's greater than or equal to now + 30 minutes. By definition that is true. What you really need is two separate functions. A function that starts the "delay" and saves the timestamp at execution. Then this second function can check if 30 minutes have passed before calling this second function.
